Vcsa 6.5 login 500 SSO error : AFD native error occured: 9234
Trying to recover a 6.5 Vcenter from an expired cert and power failure, so I can upgrade to 7.x.
When you try to log into Vcenter with FQDN, IP or netbios name it immediately gives the 500 SSO error : AFD native error occured: 9234. The PSC is running on another VM. You can log in Vcenter:5480 and everything is green and looks good. You can log into the PSC and PSC:5480. I removed the AD identity for the domain and made vsphere.local default. I ran bash tool and left the domain on both the PSC and Vcenter and rebooted both. I also ran checksts on the PSC and it was clean. I ran lsdoctor on the PSC it reported a expired machine cert for Vcenter and mismatched on the PSC. So I ran lsdoctor again with to fix. It fixed all mismatch.  I restared all services on the PSC and Vcenter. Still get the same 500 error trying to log in Vcenter.
